# How to upload image in ASP.Net core code first approach and send image using post man

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, file-upload, ef-code-first-mapping

[image]This is my model class

```
public class ImageModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    [DisplayName("Image Name")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload File")]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }


}
```

This is my controller class for post request
And I create a wwwroot folder to save Image

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    private readonly Databasecontext _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;



    

    public ImageController(Databasecontext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _context = context;
        this._hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    // GET: Image
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Images.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Image/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Image/Create

    [HttpPost]
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ImageId,Title,ImageName")] ImageModel imageModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save image to wwwroot/image
            string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
            imageModel.ImageName = fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/Image/", fileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await imageModel.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            //Insert record
            _context.Add(imageModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(imageModel);


    }
```

This is my DB context

```
 public DbSet<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
```

I just need to test this using postman and combine it with angular. Can someone help me?
when I send an image through postman I get this error The request entity has a media type that doesn't support server or resource does not support.

Comment: Hi @scorpion private, could you please share how do you post the data in Postman? I cannot reproduce the issue and post the data to action successfully.

Comment: I have added the output of the postman above

Comment: I perform that functionality by sending a base64 and the file name, when the API receives the base64 it converts it to an IFormFile and copies it to a predefined directory

Comment: Can you give me the sample code @Juan_H

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use `[ApiController]` in your controller, it allows data from body by default. So you need specific the source by using `[FromForm]` attribute like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ImageId,Title,ImageName")][FromForm] ImageModel imageModel)
{
    //..
    return View(imageModel);
}
```

Besides, if you use `[Bind("ImageId,Title,ImageName")]`, ImageFile cannot be binded to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my Spanish in the code.

This is how i upload the file in Base64 and then copy the file to a Directory.
I Pupulate the Object `ArchivoAnexoUploadDto` using a page http://base64.guru/converter/encode/file for convert a file to a base64.

I Hope tha this extract of the code will be usefull for you

1 - Controller

```
[HttpPost("UploadFileList")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileList(List<ArchivoAnexoUploadDto> fileList)
    {
        IOperationResult<object> operationResult = null;
        try
        {
            operationResult = await _fileService.UploadFileList(fileList);

            if (!operationResult.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(operationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }

            return Ok(operationResult.Entity);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(operationResult.Entity);
        }

    }
```

I Recibe a List of Objects < ArchivoAnexoUploadDto > and the service converts the base 64 to Bytes array.

2 - Service

```
public async Task<IOperationResult<object>> UploadFileList(List<ArchivoAnexoUploadDto> files)
    {
        List<ArchivoAnexoCreateDto> fileList = PrepareFileList(files);

        Response result = ValidateFiles(fileList);

        if (!result.Status)
        {
            Response responseError = new()
            {
                Status = false,
                Message = ((FormFile)result.Object).FileName,
                MessageDetail = result.Message
            };
            return OperationResult<object>.Ok(responseError);
        }

        var saveResult = await SaveFileList(fileList);

        Response respuesta = new()
        {
            Status = true,
            Message = "Los archivos fueron almacenados exitosamente.",
            MessageDetail = ""
        };
        return OperationResult<object>.Ok(respuesta);
    }


    private List<ArchivoAnexoCreateDto> PrepareFileList(List<ArchivoAnexoUploadDto> files)
    {
        List<ArchivoAnexoCreateDto> formFileList = new List<ArchivoAnexoCreateDto>();

        foreach (ArchivoAnexoUploadDto newFile in files)
        {

            byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(newFile.Base64);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(_fileSettings.PrincipalPath, _fileSettings.PrincipalFolderName, newFile.NombreArchivo);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

            FormFile fileData = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, newFile.NombreArchivo, newFile.NombreArchivo);

            ArchivoAnexoCreateDto fileDto = new()
            {
                FileId = 0,
                Data = fileData,
                FileName = newFile.NombreArchivo,
                Module = newFile.Modulo
            };
            formFileList.Add(fileDto);
        }

        return formFileList;
    }

    private Response ValidateFiles(List<ArchivoAnexoCreateDto> fileList)
    {
        foreach (ArchivoAnexoCreateDto fileObj in fileList)
        {
            IFormFile file = fileObj.Data;
            try
            {
                ValidateFile(file);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new Response { Status = false, Message = exception.Message, Object = file };
            }
        }
        return new Response { Status = true, Message = "" };
    }
```

The Service recibe the Array and `PrepareFileList` return the same data but the array have IFormFile instead of Base64 string.

3 - Dtos

```
public sealed class ArchivoAnexoUploadDto
{
    public long AnexoFileId { get; set; }
    public string Base64 { get; set; }
    public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }
    public Module Modulo {get; set;}
}

public sealed class ArchivoAnexoCreateDto
{
    public long FileId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Data { get; set; }
    public int FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

`ArchivoAnexoUploadDto` Is the Dto that recives the base64 and the name of the file.

`ArchivoAnexoCreateDto` Is the Dto with IFormFile property and is used to copy the file to a Directory.

4 - Validate IFormFile To Copy to Dir

```
private void ValidateFile(IFormFile fileToCreate)
    {
        if (fileToCreate == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No ha enviado ningun archivo.");
        }

        IOperationResult<string> fileExtensionResult = _fileService.GetFileExtension(fileToCreate);

        if (!fileExtensionResult.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception(fileExtensionResult.ErrorMessage);
        }

        if (!_fileSettings.AllowedExtensions.Contains(fileExtensionResult.Entity))
        {
            throw new Exception("La extención del archivo no es permitida.");
        }

        IOperationResult<long> fileSizeResult = _fileService.GetFileSize(fileToCreate);

        if (!fileSizeResult.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ha ocurrido un error obteniendo el tamaño del archivo.");
        }

        if (fileSizeResult.Entity > _fileSettings.MaxFileSize)
        {
            throw new Exception("El tamaño del archivo supera el limite.");
        }
    }
```

This are Conditions for validate (Only for explain) I Did this stuff because the business configured a list of extensions, a size limit of the files, etc.